# How to convert string to double?

Tags: php, oracle

When I select from DB Oracle the value `-0.10` but it was selected type string and value `-1`, why?

```
$query_for_balance = "select balance_$ from bis.client_balance_rate_plan where msisdn=$gett";
$per_for_balance = oci_parse($conn, $query_for_balance);
oci_execute($per_for_balance);
oci_fetch_all($per_for_balance, $arr_for_balance);
$balance_1 = $arr_for_balance['BALANCE_$'];
$balance_2 =$$balance_1[0];
echo($balance_2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo number_format((float) $value, 2, '.', '');` is what you want?

(float) is not needed here, it just convert from string to float.

To convert to a float you just need to do a cast like this:

```
$valueString = '-0.10'; 
$valueFloat = (float) $valueString;
```

Comment: $query_for_balance = "select balance_$ from bis.client_balance_rate_plan where msisdn=$gett";
$per_for_balance = oci_parse($conn, $query_for_balance);
oci_execute($per_for_balance);
oci_fetch_all($per_for_balance, $arr_for_balance);
$balance_1 = $arr_for_balance['BALANCE_$'];
$balance = number_format((float)$balance_1[0], 2, '.', '');
echo($balance);
//result     0.00

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are accidentally using a variable variable:

```
$balance_2 = $$balance_1[0];
             ^^ here
```

This will to unexpected results as you will try to get the first element of a non-existing variable and that will probably lead to `false` / `-1`.

You probably want:

```
 // get the first element of the `balance_$` column
$balance_2 = $balance_1[0];
```

Comment: I have converted it.. but result 0.00      This is my code$query_for_balance = "select balance_$ from bis.client_balance_rate_plan where msisdn=$gett";
$per_for_balance = oci_parse($conn, $query_for_balance);
oci_execute($per_for_balance);
oci_fetch_all($per_for_balance, $arr_for_balance);
$balance_1 = $arr_for_balance['BALANCE_$'];
$balance = number_format((float)$balance_1[0], 2, '.', '');
echo($balance);

Answer (score 0):

To convert in float, you just need to use following code :

```
$balance_2 = floatval($balance_1[0]);
```